# How can I intercept log messages in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I am currently logging messages using a combination of:

```
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

[...]

if (log.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
    log.log(Level.INFO, message);
}
```

Is there a way I can intercept all log messages before they reach the console so that I can, for example, persist them in the database?

Similar to how `HandlerInterceptor` can intercept web requests?

Comment: You can define Aspect on your logger class method like on debug,info and error methods for this

Comment: Intercepting log events using an Aspect requires to manage/inject the logger-component by spring (otherwise there's no simple way to weave the advice around). Another option would be using appenders. In case you are using `logback`, have a look at `ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender`, or implement your own.